# Buttons that need to change their .innerHTML but they are made in a loop so they end up having the same id

Tags: javascript, html, loops, button

I am writing a table tree in javascript for xml files, and I need button for each .  When this button is clicked it needs to have its text change from "-" to "+" and vice a versa.  I know normally the following code would work;

```
function change()
{
    if(document.getElementsById("myButton").innerHTML == "-"){
        document.getElementById("myButton").innerHTML = "+";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("myButton").innerHTML = "-";
    }
}
```

The reason I cannot just use this is because the buttons are created in a loop so they all have the same Id.

If you could help me to either make it so each time the button is made its Id has an incrementing number appended to it, or have another means of doing the above code it would be helpful.

Comment: There's no need for the elements to have the same `id`; indeed, there's no real need for the elements to have an `id` at all, probably! Could you show your code to generate the buttons?

Comment: They can't have the same ID. The `id` attribute is supposed to be unique.

Comment: Multiple elements should NEVER have the same id. The id is supposed to be a unique reference. The code generating the button needs to be rewritten.

Comment: How are you *calling* this function?

Comment: I am well aware this is taboo to have non-unique ids. I cannot show the actual code due to the proprietary information it is used on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use an ID at all; instead pass the element to modify as an argument to the `change` function. The function would now look like this:

```
function change(element)
{
    if(element.innerHTML == "-"){
        element.innerHTML = "+";
    }
    else{
        element.innerHTML = "-";
    }
}
```

Then, when you create your buttons, the `onclick` attribute would look like this:

```
onclick="change(this);"
```

Comment: Or even simpler, if the `change()` function is assigned as the event handler, you can use the `this` reference instead.

Comment: `element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.indexOf('-') > -1 ? '+' : '-';`

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

When you are looping through creating each button, create a counter variable, or use the variable from the for loop, and each loop increment it by 1 and append that to the ID.

```
for(var i = 0; i < some_number; i++){
  var ID = "myButton"+i;
  //Other code
}
```

Comment: How would I then add that to the html line?

Comment: You could do something like var htmlString = '<button id="'+ID+'" type="button">